# Which is better printf or echo?

Tags: command-line

For displaying message and print data there are two command available `printf` and `echo`.

Then how differently they used? Which is more preferable?

Comment: You will find the answer here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Preferable and most widely used is not the same thing. While `printf` is better for many reasons, most people still use `echo` because the syntax is simpler.

**The main reasons why you should prefer `printf` are:**

1. `echo` is not standardized, it will behave differently on different systems.
2. It is hard to predict what you're actually running when you `echo foo`. To illustrate, on my Debian system:

   ```
   $ type -a echo
   echo is a shell builtin
   echo is /bin/echo
   ```

   As you can see, there are two different `echo` commands, one is a shell (bash in this case) builtin and another is a separate binary. Note that `bash` also has a `printf` builtin but its behavior is more standardized so it is less of an issue (thanks to @  RaduRădeanu for pointing it out).
3. Since some (but not all) implementations of `echo` support command line switches, it is hard to print a string that starts with a `-`. While many programs support `--` to signify the end of switches and the beginning of arguments (for example, `grep -- -a file` will find lines in `file` that contain `-a`), `echo` does not. So, how do you have `echo` print `-n`?

   ```
   $ echo -n           ## no output
   $ echo '-n'         ## no output
   $ echo "-n"         ## no output
   $ echo \-n          ## no output
   $ echo -e '\055n'   ## using the ASCII code works but only on implementations
   -n                  ## that support -e
   ```

   `printf` can do this easily:

   ```
   $ printf -- '-n\n'
   -n
   $ printf '%s\n' -n
   -n
   $ printf '\055n\n' 
   -n
   ```

For more information than you ever wanted to know on why `printf` is better than `echo`, see this answer to a similar question on http://unix.stackexchange.com:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22222

Comment: Given good answer. It helps me to prefer `printf` as better interpreter.

Comment: At the point 2: the same is true for `printf` (see `type -a`).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu true, but `printf` is more rigidly [defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) in POSIX and I think the builtin follows the same standard. The POSIX [specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for `echo` on the other hand are less strict and even explicitly state that there will be differences between implementations and that `printf` should be preferred.

Comment: Wow. So there are **literally zero objective technical advantages to using `echo`.** Is that correct?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude no, absolutely no technical advantage whatsoever. The only reason to use `echo` rather than `printf` is that the forma can be simpler. If you know what you're printing, `echo foo` is faster and easier to type than `printf 'foo\n'`. Apart from that, when writing scripts where a variable needs to be printed, there's never a good reason to use `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

To ask which is preferable is itself incomplete.

If all one wishes to do is emit one or more lines of text **terminated by newlines**, then echo suffices.  If anything more clever is intended, specifically including a "partial line" that does not have the newline, then printf is best *for that purpose*.

Comment: Depending on the `echo` implementation, "avoiding the newline" is easily done with `echo -n`. In fact, `-n` is the most portable of echo's features. According to POSIX, it is absent from SystemV but present in most Unices.

Comment: I've worked in enough different unices to not even try avoiding newlines with echo.  Writing scripts that are portable across SCO, AIX, HP-UX, and Linux is... challenging.

Comment: Oh absolutely, no argument there. All I'm, saying is that the newline is the least of the problems. All bets are off as soon as you try to port to a non-GNU system. I _think_ you can rely on the `-n` for the BSDs and SystemV but anything else, I have no idea.